# creating conditional flag basis the multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id       Month        Year       scheduled         completed
A         Jan         2021           0                 0
A         Feb         2021           1                 0
A         mar         2021           0                 0
B         June        2021           0                 1
B         July        2021           0                 1
B         Aug         2021           0                 1
B         Sep         2021           0                 1
C         Nov         2021           1                 0
C         Dec         2021           1                 0
C         Jan         2022           1                 0
C         Feb         2022           1                 0
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
 Id           status
 A          defaulter
 B          non_defaulter
 C          defaulter
```

I am trying to create a status tag for each basis their activity. if for three consecutive Month if **completed** column remains 0 , that Id is to be tagged as "defaulter" else "non_defaulter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is aggregate per consecutive groups of `0` values per `Id` and helper Series `s` created by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), count `True`s values, then because possible multiple groups per `Id` aggregate `max` and last set values in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
N = 3
m = df['completed'].ne(0)
#if need check in completed OR scheduled column
#m = df[['completed','scheduled']].ne(0).any(axis=1)

df = ((~m).groupby([df['Id'], m.cumsum().mask(m, -1)])
          .sum()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .max()
          .reset_index(name='status')
          .assign(status = lambda x: np.where(x['status'].ge(N), 
                                            'defaulter','non_defaulter')))
       
print (df)
  Id         status
0  A      defaulter
1  B  non_defaulter
2  C      defaulter
```

Comment: what if we need to check the condition in scheduled or completed..?(currently we are checking on completed column) what would be the change in above code

Comment: @Roshankumar - Give me a second

Comment: @Roshankumar - Use `m = df[['completed','scheduled']].ne(0).any(axis=1)` for `completed OR scheduled column`, if need `m = df[['completed','scheduled']].ne(0).all(axis=1)` for `completed AND scheduled column`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a double [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to count the consecutive 1s in `completed`, then to ensure there is at least 1 stretch greater or equal to `N=3`:

```
N = 3

# is the row a zero?
m = df['completed'].eq(0)

# count the consecutive zeros
(m.groupby([df['Id'], (~m).cumsum()])
   .sum().ge(N)
   # check if there is at least one stretch of value >= N
   .groupby(level=0).any()
   # convert the True/False into strings
   .map({False: 'non_defaulter', True: 'defaulter'})
   .reset_index(name='status')
)
```

Output:

```
  Id         status
0  A      defaulter
1  B  non_defaulter
2  C      defaulter
```